# How unique can give me the size of a container in C++?

Tags: c++

why does these results are different?
if you look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void reduce(long ar[], int n)
{
long ar[]= {1, 4, 34, 1, 4, 67, 15 ,3 ,2 ,1, 34};

std::sort(ar, ar+n);
int size = std::unique(ar, ar+n) - ar; 
std::cout << size << std::endl; // here size =7
std::cout << (int)(std::unique(ar, ar+n) - ar); // here we get 10!
}`
```

Comment: This makes about zero sense.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you're asking? [`std::unique()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) removes the duplicates from the sequence (range), and returns the new end of that sequence (range). Thus calculating the difference of these iterators tells you the actual size of the container.

Comment: If this is `std::unique`, have you looked up some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)? Is there something you don't understand in the documentation?

Comment: I re-read your question thrice, can't get it

Comment: It'll me make me uniquely fool, I still don't get it...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It doesn't actually yield the size of the container, but the size of the unique range. The container can be larger (in both size and capacity).

Comment: @dyp _"It doesn't actually yield the size of the container"_ Where did I say that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "tells you the actual size of the container" Maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Do you have some example code that shows that the two ways of calculation result in different values? Because they should both return the same number.

Comment: @dyp OK, got it now. You're nitpicking about container's reserved size vs number of contained elements. Well, yes.

Comment: We would need to know the prototype of this function to be able to debug, as the return value is likely being automatically converted to *some type* but we don't know which one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, not really. `std::unique` doesn't erase elements, it *re-moves* them. The size of the container does not change, the iterator interface does not allow such a modification. (The capacity is unchanged as well, but that's not really the point I wanted to make.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, the number of "contained elements" in e.g. a vector would remain unchanged by `std::unique()`. You would have to call `std::vector::resize()` for example in order to actually remove the elements completely from the container. (`vec.resize(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()) - vec.begin())`)

Comment: @cdhowie I think the erase-remove idiom could be applied here as well: `vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end())`

Comment: @dyp Indeed, that is probably more readable, too.

Comment: Does someone know why these two expressions does not yield the same result but 7 for one and 10 for the other?

Comment: @user3810322 Yes, but let's reopen the question first.

Comment: ok how can I reopen the question?

Comment: I don't think *you* can reopen the question, only users with [> 3000 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) can cast a reopen vote. Three users have done that already, five are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we can, for example, look at the array to see what happens. [Live demonstration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b1a7cdc0bbc40f2)

```
1  1  1  2  3  4  4 15 34 34 67 // after sorting
1  2  3  4 15 34 67 15 34 34 67 // after calling unique
7 // size
1  2  3  4 15 34 67 15 34 67 67 // after calling unique
10 // size
```

After calling `std::unique` for the first time, the range [`ar`, `ar+n`) is **no longer sorted**. `unique` removes *consecutive* duplicate elements, and returns an iterator pointing to the end of the so-called "unique" range. This range [`ar`, `ar+size`) (specified in terms of the first iterator passed and the returned iterator) is guaranteed not to contain any *consecutive* duplicates. **The content of the remaining (following) elements is unspecified.**

```
1  1  1  2  3  4  4 15 34 34 67        // after sorting
1  2  3  4 15 34 67 15 34 34 67        // after calling unique
^ ar+0              ^           ^ ar+n
                    | iterator returned by first call to unique
####################~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`#` Range without consecutive duplicates
`~` Contents unspecified

When you call `unique` the second time, it cannot make the range truly unique since it is no longer sorted in [`ar`, `ar+n`), but only in [`ar`, `ar+size`). The remaining unspecified elements happen to be such that there are now 10 consecutively different elements:

```
1  1  1  2  3  4  4 15 34 34 67        // after sorting
1  2  3  4 15 34 67 15 34 34 67        // after calling unique
1  2  3  4 15 34 67 15 34 67 67        // after calling unique
^ ar+0              ^        ^  ^ ar+n
                    |        | iterator returned by second call to unique
                    | iterator returned by first call to unique
```

Note that the range [`ar+0`, iterator returned by second call to unique) does not contain any *consecutive* duplicates.